# Adding each User Name to wp_mail() in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, email

I have a front end form which then sends an email to all users within a certain user role. It's sending fine but within the email itself, it's printing out the last users' name (from the list of users within the user role), in all recipients emails.

I'm sure it's something to do with my array and/or variable/s that I've setup incorrectly. Any help would be appreciated on how each user will receive an email and the correct name will be printed out for them!

Here's my code:

```
// Get users and their roles.
$user_args = array(
'role__in' => 'test_role', 
'orderby'  => 'user_nicename',
 'order'    => 'ASC'
);

$users = get_users($user_args);

$user_name_list = array();

foreach ( $users as $user ) :
    $user_email_list[] = $user->user_email;
    $user_name_list[]  = $user->display_name;
endforeach;

$user_name = $user_name_list;

// This is part of the code that adds their username to the email content.
$body  = '<p style="margin-bottom: 20px;">Hello ' . $user_name . ',</p>';
```

Comment: Answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43833428/using-a-variable-outside-php-foreach-loop

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the code , you are printing an array instead actually.

```
// Get users and their roles.
$user_args = array(
'role__in' => 'test_role', 
'orderby'  => 'user_nicename',
 'order'    => 'ASC'
);

$users = get_users($user_args);

$user_name_list = array();

foreach ( $users as $user ) :
    $user_email_list[] = $user->user_email;
    $user_name_list[]  = $user->display_name;

  $user_info = get_userdata($user-> ID);
  $username = $user_info->user_login;
  $first_name = $user_info->first_name;
  $last_name = $user_info->last_name;

endforeach;

$user_name = $user_name_list;

// This is part of the code that adds their username to the email content.
$body  = '<p style="margin-bottom: 20px;">Hello ' . $user_name . ',</p>';
```

May be that will help.

Comment: It didn't work sorry. My Array prints out like this:                                      
Array
(
    [0] => Person One
    [1] => Person Two
    [2] => Person Three
    [3] => Person Four
    [4] => Person Five
)

With your code I got Person One

Comment: I have updated the code to get the first name and last name , but I didn't get  if you want to send out emails with all the user info or not?