# Using a variable outside PHP Foreach Loop

Tags: arrays, wordpress, email

I am trying to output a username and user email outside of a foreach loop. I am trying to send an email to all WordPress users that are within a certain User Role.

Here is my code:

```
// Get users and their roles
    $user_args = array(
      'role__in' => 'new_role', 
      'orderby'  => 'user_nicename',
      'order'    => 'ASC'
    );  
    $users = get_users($user_args); 

    foreach ( $users as $user ) :       
        $user_name  = $user->user_email;
        $user_email = $user->display_name;          
    endforeach;
```

So I can then use them in other areas of the page, ie:.

```
echo 'Hello, ' . $user_name;
echo 'Send to: ' .$user_email;
```

I've printed out the $users array which contains the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => WP_User Object
        (
            [data] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [ID] => 46
                    [user_login] => huw
                    [user_pass] => u7CqxbuQDvApUAF6tT.
                    [user_nicename] => huw
                    [user_email] => huw@xxxx.co.uk
                    [user_url] => 
                    [user_registered] => 2017-02-06 11:13:09
                    [user_activation_key] => 1486379590:$P$BkisA4T5j1S/ZjRageafNYHfsdin1S0
                    [user_status] => 0
                    [display_name] => Huw Daniel Rowlands
                )

            [ID] => 46
            [caps] => Array
                (
                    [sssg] => 1
                    [new_role] => 1
                    [site_member] => 1
                    [test_role] => 1
                )

            [cap_key] => jciw_capabilities
            [roles] => Array
                (
                    [0] => sssg
                    [1] => new_role
                    [2] => site_member
                    [3] => test_role
                )

            [allcaps] => Array
                (
                    [read] => 1
                    [sssg] => 1
                    [new_role] => 1
                    [site_member] => 1
                    [test_role] => 1
                )

            [filter] => 
        )

    [1] => WP_User Object
        (
            [data] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [ID] => 308
                    [user_login] => jeremy
                    [user_pass] => LLOKbkPOWQsBKUIk2qL1
                    [user_nicename] => magnus
                    [user_email] => jeremy@gmail.com
                    [user_url] => 
                    [user_registered] => 2017-05-03 19:24:42
                    [user_activation_key] => 1493839482:$P$BI/IYldCzsXZowLEiNfxiUkIwVdDKV0
                    [user_status] => 0
                    [display_name] => Jeremy
                )

            [ID] => 308
            [caps] => Array
                (
                    [new_role] => 1
                    [sssg] => 1
                    [site_member] => 1
                )

            [cap_key] => jciw_capabilities
            [roles] => Array
                (
                    [0] => new_role
                    [1] => sssg
                    [2] => site_member
                )

            [allcaps] => Array
                (
                    [read] => 1
                    [new_role] => 1
                    [sssg] => 1
                    [site_member] => 1
                )

            [filter] => 
        )

)
```

Comment: I am confused as to what you are trying to do. If you want to save 'user_name' and 'user_email' in your foreach loop, you will simply be overwriting the variable each time until the last iteration. It seems as if you are expecting only one user though, is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to send an email to all users with a certain role, try something like this:

```
// Get users and their roles
$user_args = array(
  'role__in' => 'new_role', 
  'orderby'  => 'user_nicename',
  'order'    => 'ASC'
);

$users = get_users($user_args); 

foreach ( $users as $user ) :       
    $user_email  = $user->user_email;
    $user_name = $user->display_name;
    send_email($user_name, $user_email);          
endforeach;
```

And then write your email function:

```
function send_email($name, $email) {
    // Do email sending stuff here with $name & $email
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Chris for the help. I've modified my code now to include this:

    `foreach ( $users as $user ) :  
  $user_name  = $user->user_email;
  $user_email = $user->display_name;
  send_email( $user_name, $user_email );
 endforeach;`

And then created a function with the email content required:

`function send_email($user_name, $user_email) {
// Body content in here...
wp_mail($admin_email, $subject, $body, $headers); 
}`

But am not getting any emails.

Comment: @HuwRowlands where is `$admin_email` coming from? Should that be `$user_email` instead? (Also I am assuming `$subject`, `$body`, and `$headers` are defined prior to use, correct?

Comment: Sorry. I've updated my function call to include some other variables:

`function send_email($user_name, $user_email, $admin_email, $post_id, $cat_list) {`

These are predefined. `$admin_email` is for sending an email to the admin of the website.

 `$headers = array(
  'From: Admin <'.$admin_email.'>\r\n',
  'To:  Admin <'.$admin_email.'>\r\n',
  'Bcc: '.$user_name.'<'.$user_email.'>\r\n'
  );`

Comment: @HuwRowlands I'm not too familiar with the `wp_mail()` function, but I would recommend printing out all those variables to the screen each loop so that way you can verify the variables are properly set

Comment: Simplified my code & the $user_name & $user_email variables are outputting incorrectly. $user_name is outputting the email address & $user_email is outputting the name?! This happens only outside the foreach loop when calling the function.

Comment: `function sendEmail( $user_name, $user_email ) {    
    echo 'Name: ' . $user_name . ' Email: ' . $user_email . '<br />';
} 

$user_args = array(
 'role__in' => 'new_role', 
 'orderby'  => 'user_nicename',
 'order'    => 'ASC'
); 
$users = get_users($user_args); 
foreach ( $users as $user ) :  
 $user_name  = $user->user_email;
 $user_email = $user->display_name;
 sendEmail( $user_name, $user_email );
 //echo 'User: ' . $user_email . ' - ' . $user_name . '<br />';
endforeach;`

Comment: Oh thats my bad.. I have them swapped in the foreach. Check my edit

Comment: Thanks @chris I thought I was going crazy!!

Comment: @HuwRowlands I'll take the blame on that one, I'm not sure how I messed that up haha. Please mark the answer as accepted if it worked :)